# What do you call a single sentence (in a whole response) that solves all the problems?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, let's see my question in Academia: [I may not be admitted to the school that have the professor I have interest in. What should I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61022/14341)

So I know that I shouldn't put all my eggs in one basket. In fact, I know most of the reasons behind the top answer. However, until that top answer appears, no answer and comment could enlighten me. The different between that answer and other answers is one single sentence in a whole answer:

> Yes, that might mean changing your proposed research, but your research career will span decades; there's plenty of time to go back to your initial proposal later.

After reading this one, my mind is suddenly clear, and I feel that I don't need to read the rest of the answer to know what to do. It seems that my mind has been stuck somewhere, and this sentence unstuck it.

How should I call this sentence?

Comment: Perhaps an *eye-opener* (an unexpectedly enlightening fact).

Comment: Also epiphany or a revelation.

Comment: I'm wondering what you call this sentence: *In fact, I know most of the reasons the top answer given.*

Comment: The grand unified field theory ?

Comment: @HotLicks I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @BlessedGeek what?

Comment: @Ooker - What is it supposed to mean?  It makes no sense.

Comment: It means for example it gives 10 bullets, then I have known 9 of them. Only the last one is what I'm looking for

Comment: But that's not what it says.  It's gibberish.

Comment: Sorry ... Grand unified theory, not Grand unified field theory.

Comment: @HotLicks so how to make it right?

Comment: @BlessedGeek I also study physics. Can you tell me what's relevant here?

Comment: I still haven't got a clue what you're trying to say.  Is it "I know most of the reasons behind the top answer"?  Or "I know most of the higher-rated answers"?  Or what?

Comment: @HotLicks It's "I know most of the reasons behind the top answer". Can you tell me what's wrong with the old version?

Comment: More informally, the particular sentence totally **nailed it!** :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's an interesting question. I have edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From vocabulary.com:

> [***incisive***](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/incisive) -
>
> The adjective incisive describes something that is sharp, decisive, and direct. A comment that cuts right to the bone can be just as incisive as an actual knife.
>
> The word incisive is rooted in a Latin word that literally means "to cut with a sharp edge." To help you remember the meaning, you can think of the similar word, incisors, which are the teeth that are sharp and cut and tear. The more figurative meaning of describing something that is mentally sharp first appeared in the 1850s. Keen criticism and cutting remarks have been called incisive ever since.

I would add that *incisive* is not a perfect synonym for *cutting*, which more often implies wounding criticism. The remark you quote is not a *cutting remark*, but an *incisive* comment.

Comment: when should I use *remark* instead of *comment*?

Comment: With *incisive*, either is fine.   With *cutting*-- again because it is an adjective for criticism-- *remark* is more common than *comment*, just because the connotation for *comment* is more mild.